# Using ArcPy to find duplicate values in feature class

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to create a toolkit to find duplicate cable values in a Feature class.
I have a shp layer named Fiber_Cable stored in an sde database and I want to iterate over it to find duplicate values of the "REFERENCE" field.
it doesn't work with this script. anyone see where the error can come from ?

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os
import re   #regex
import sys  #Fonction systeme pour exit du programme
import csv
import time


base = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sortie = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fichier_sde = ur"J:\DOCUMENT_POLE_DATA\OUTIL\SDE\{}_WSCRIPT_INTEGRATION_02.sde".format(base)
chemin_cable=ur"J:\DOCUMENT_POLE_DATA\OUTIL\SDE\ {}_WSCRIPT_INTEGRATION_02.sde\NETEDESIGNER.FiberCable".format(base)`enter 

arcpy.env.workspace = chemin_cable
champ_a_verfier = "REFERENCE"  # colonne à vérifier 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(chemin_cable, [champ_a_verfier]) as rows:
    values = [r[0] for r in rows]
    arcpy.AddMessage(values)
del rows           

d = {}
for item in set(values):
    if values.count(item) > 1:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Please check the cable with the following 
        reference {} ".format(values))    
        d[item] = 'Y'
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("There is no duplicate cable in the layer 
        FiberCable")    
        d[item] = 'N'

#Export cvs File

csv_file=os.path.join(sortie, "DuplicatesCables.csv")

try:
    with open (csv_file, 'w') as csvfile :
        writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=d['Y','N']
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    arcpy.AddMessage("I/O error")
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself already?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. If your title has an "and" in it, it's likely the Question is not focused enough. It's certainly possible to both detect duplicates and export to CSV (and there are multiple ways to accomplish both), but you need to choose one, make the attempt, encounter a problem, attempt to fix the problem, then [Edit] the Question to document the issue.

Comment: hello, I modified my question by adding the code I just tried.

Comment: Why are you writing all this code?  Are you aware of the [Find Identical tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm)?

Comment: pls can you add Error Msg here for Clarity.

Comment: @Hornbydd I don't have the advanced to do this !

Comment: I see several syntax errors. For example, the lines defined by these variables: `fichier_sde` and `chemin_cable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code and it worked. Here is the solution if anyone is interested or has the same problem.

```
champ_a_verfier = ["REFERENCE"]  # colonne à vérifier
values={}
values["Ref_Nulle"]=0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(chem_caftth, champ_a_verfier) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] in [None,""]:
            values["Ref_Nulle"]+=1
        else:
            if r[0] not in values:
                values[r[0]]=1
            else:
                values[r[0]]+=1 
 del rows

 dictDoublons = {}
 dictPasDoublons = {}
 cable_cda = 'CDA'
 count = 0
 for item in values:
    if values[item] > 1:
        if not item.startswith("CDA"):
            dictDoublons[item] = 'Doublons'
        count+=1
        arcpy.AddWarning('Il y a {} cables en doublons  a Verifier / Corriger.'.format(count))
    else:   
        dictPasDoublons[item] = 'PasDoublons'
```

"""
function export CSV
"""

```
   def exportCsvDoublons(dict):
       csv_file= open(os.path.join(sortie, 'CablesEnDoublons_{}_'.format(cou) + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")) +'.csv'), 'w')
       writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
       for key, value in dict.items():
           writer.writerow([key, value])
       csv_file.close()



   exportCsvDoublons(dictDoublons)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I have numerous comments, I thought putting them in an Answer might be easier.

First, I understand from the comments you don't have an ArcGIS Desktop Advanced licenses, which means the [Find Identical](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) tool is unavailable to you.  Hence why you are writing your own code.

My next comment is nitpicky, so take it with a grain of salt, but semantics can make a difference when asking questions and getting answers.

*Saying something is a "shp layer" may lead to confusion that you are talking about a shape file since shape files are still a common data format.  Although I am guessing you are working with a feature layer, even just saying "layer" would reduce any risk of possible confusion.  More importantly, layers aren't stored in geodatabases, data sets are stored in them.  The layer you speak of exists outside the geodatabase and references a data set within the geodatabase.*

Looking over the code, the logic seems sound, but what I do notice is that `data_dict` isn't defined anywhere in the code you provided.  Did you mean to loop over `d` instead?

Comment: thank you very much for your comments, i take them into consideration. i tried again, i modified the code to run faster and it worked.